# Are there simple conditions on a Fréchet differentiable function on a Hilbert space that ensure that the Fréchet derivatives are trace-class?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, trace, frechet-derivative

Let $H$ be a separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $f:H\to H$ be Fréchet differentiable. Are there "simple" conditions on $f$ that ensure that the Fréchet derivatives ${\rm D}f(x)\in\mathfrak L(H)$ are trace-class for all $x\in H$?